# What is the proper way to change look of MapView zoom controls in Android?

Tags: android

What is the proper way to change look of MapView zoom controls in Android?

I want to repoduce zoom button from new google maps.

[image]

Comment: I don't know for how can change default mapview default zoom control, but we can disable it and then using our custom button we can add zoom functionality manually. If this help you. Let me know what you thought about this. Have you tried about this?

Answer (score 2):

i have done this.the default controls come on the bottom of the map and i wanted it to be top of the map.i used this.

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:layout_below="@+id/layout_zoom" 
    android:id="@+id/mapview" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:clickable="true" 
    android:apiKey="key" />



<ZoomControls android:id="@+id/zoomControls" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></ZoomControls>
```

then in the MapActivity class set zoom controls

```
 MapView mp = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    ZoomControls zoomControls = (ZoomControls) findViewById(R.id.zoomControls);
    zoomControls
            .setOnZoomInClickListener(new ZoomControls.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mp.getController().zoomIn();
                }
            });
    zoomControls
            .setOnZoomOutClickListener(new ZoomControls.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mp.getController().zoomOut();
                }
            });
```

you can set this listeners to your own button also. 
hope it will help.

Comment: I want to change style of zoom controls button. They should look like image sample.

Answer (score 0):

Using the MapView API turn off the default zoom controls, using your layout overlay the desired widgets, tie their click event listeners to the `MapController`'s `setZoomLevel`.